# Dynamic Instantiation In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object

I have a drop-down list containing classifications of currencies which can be instantiated as a JavaScript "class".  I currently use a switch statement to accomplish this, but I'm absolutely sure there's a more eloquent way to do so.  So, can anyone out there show me a better way?

**Is There a Better Way To Dynamically Instantiate a Class?:**

```
function ddlCurrency_selectedIndexChanged() {

    var currency = null;

    switch (this.value) {
        case "Dollar":
            currency = new Dollar(null);
            break;
     case "Reais":
            currency = new Reais(null);
                break;
    }

    // Do something with the class here
};
```

**Here Are The Classes:**
Just in case you wanted to see them.

```
// ------------------------
// CLASS - Base Class
function Currency(country, code, imageURL, name) {
    this.country = country;     //EXAMPLE: America
    this.code = code;   //EXAMPLE: USD
    this.imageURL = imageURL;   //EXAMPLE: "http://someplace/mySymbol.gif"
    this.name = name;   //EXAMPLE: Dollar
    this.amount = parseFloat("0.00");   //EXAMPLE: 100
};

// CLASS
function Pound(imageURL) {
    Currency.call(this, "Greate Britain", "GBP", imageURL, "Pound");
};
Pound.prototype = new Currency();
Pound.prototype.constructor = Pound;

// CLASS
function Dollar(imageURL) {
    Currency.call(this, "America", "USD", imageURL, "Dollar");
};
Dollar.prototype = new Currency();
Dollar.prototype.constructor = Dollar;

// CLASS
function Reais(imageURL) {
    Currency.call(this, "Brazil", "BRL", imageURL, "Reais");
};
Reais.prototype = new Currency();
Reais.prototype.constructor = Reais;
```

**UPDATE:**
Using `eval()` also works. Oddly enough, I've seen people voted downward for using it...although, I don't know why.  Personally, I'm inclined to like it better because you may not have anything coming-off of the `window` object.  A good example of that is in the case of certain AMD-style asynchronously loaded objects...they do not hang-off `window`.

EXAMPLE using eval:

```
var currency = eval('new Dollar()');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic instantiation in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029329/dynamic-instantiation-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your top level object is window (in case you are in a browser):

```
currency = new window[this.value](null);
```

This works since all your classes are just properties of the global object and `window[property]` retrieves a property.

Comment: How would I do it without window?

Comment: Just found it, but is using eval() considered evil?

Comment: Can we do this in a node.js environment?