# How to instantiate class dynamically

Tags: javascript, oop

I have an array with names of constructors `var arr = ['Class1', 'Class2', 'Class3']`.

```
function Class1() {
     this.name = 'class1';
}
```

Is it possible to dynamically create instances of these classes? I mean something like

```
var class1Object = new arr[0]();
```

I tried that but it isn't working (Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function).

Answer (score 2):

functions defined in "global" scope are actually created on the `window` object, so you can do this (as long as the code is in the `head` of the page, and not scoped to something specific):

```
function Class1(){
    this.name = 'class1';
}

var className = "Class1";
var c1 = new window[className]();
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/vdf4W/

Comment: If it's a real class `class Class1 { ... }` as is possible since ES6, this doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 0):

Previously answered in this post (Google: Dynamic Instantiation In JavaScript)

[Dynamic Instantiation In JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914108/dynamic-instantiation-in-javascript)

Comment: This could be just a comment.