# Dynamic instantiation in JavaScript [Classname as String]

Tags: javascript, dynamic, sapui5

I am working with Javascript and Appdescriptors in JSON format.
What I want to do is creating a instance of a Class, where the classname is saved as string in `oModelConf[sModelName].type`. If that is not the case I want to take  `"sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel"`

[Related Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029329/dynamic-instantiation-in-javascript/31195117#comment60040239_31195117) offers this solution:

```
function instantiate(className, args) {
    var o, f, c;
    c = window[className]; // get reference to class constructor function
    f = function(){}; // dummy function
    f.prototype = c.prototype; // reference same prototype
    o = new f(); // instantiate dummy function to copy prototype properties
    c.apply(o, args); // call class constructor, supplying new object as context
    o.constructor = c; // assign correct constructor (not f)
    return o;
}
```

This is not a very good solution I think.

**EDIT** It does not work for me because my class is not defined on window, so `window[className]` is undefined. I do not know where my function is defined in SAPUI5

A second Solution:

```
eval(`a = new ${oModelConf[sModelName].type || "sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel"}(sServiceUrl, true);`);
```

This is not a better solution because we should not use `eval()`.

**Are there any better solutions?**

**EDIT2**
Because of [the url in pimskies answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9804142/5930258) I found an other solution:

Since `window.sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel` is the same as `sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel` and `window.sap` is the same as `window[sap]`
I could take my string, and replace all `.` with `][`, put the right brackets to front and end.

I will not code that because it is not a going solution.(I should not have coded the `eval`thing too...)

Comment: So, does the 2nd solution work at all?  I know that God kills a kitten every time eval runs, but does it at least instantiate an object of the desired class?

Comment: @AronBoyette Yes that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [jQuery.sap.getObject](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/jQuery.sap.html#.getObject) to access the class:

```js
var ModelClass = jQuery.sap.getObject(oModelConf[sModelName].type || "sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel");
var model = new ModelClass();
```

---

Edit: An other way (which i would recommend if you use AMD)

If you are using the modern [AMD modules](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/f665d0de4dba405f9af4294de824b03b.html) and you don't know if the module containing your class has already been loaded, you should use [sap.ui.require()](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.html#.require) to load the module asynchronously. It requires the module to be specified via its [unified resource name](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/jQuery.sap.html#.getResourcePath) (the conversion is probably the most ugly part):

```
var className = oModelConf[sModelName].type || "sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel";
var urn = className.replace(".", "/"); //Convert to unified resource name
sap.ui.require([urn],function(ModelClass){
  //This function is called when the module is available
  var model = new ModelClass();
  ...
});
```

Comment: I've just stumbled about dynamic model instantiation in the sap.ui.core.Component (the model type has been read from the manifest.json): [it uses jQuery.sap.getObject()](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/rel-1.34/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/Component.js#L787)

Comment: I am doing exactly that instantiation. Because I am erlier than version 1.30, this gets not done automaticly, hop we will update soon.. It works like that thx!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe map the string to a class?

```
function Foo() {
  console.log('new foo');
}

function Bar() {
  console.log('new bar');
}

var objects = {
    'foo': Foo,
  'bar': Bar
};

var cls = objects.foo || Bar;

new cls();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ckd56d9v/1/

Or take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9804142/5930258

Comment: found something see my edit. Your first solution would work, but I do not know if there will ever come a new object (e.g `baz`) so this will need a lot of support which I do not want to

Answer (score 0):

What not combine the two?  Since `window[className]` is failing, replace it with
`oModelConf[className].type || sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel`...

```
function instantiate(className, args) {
    var o, f, c;
    c = oModelConf[className] || sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel;
    f = function(){}; // dummy function
    f.prototype = c.prototype; // reference same prototype
    o = new f(); // instantiate dummy function to copy prototype properties
    c.apply(o, args); // call class constructor, supplying new object as context
    o.constructor = c; // assign correct constructor (not f)
    return o;
}
```

Comment: `window[className]` is failing, because my className is not just an Object but a subproperty of a subproperty.. `window[class][name]` would work.